# C2664 при прямой передаче параметра функции

Tags: c++

```
class Person
{
public:
    template <
        typename T,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<
            !std::is_base_of<Person,std::decay_t<T>>::value &&
            !std::is_integral<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value
        >
    >
        explicit Person(T&& n) :
        name(std::forward<T>(n))
    {

    }
private:
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    Person p(u"Konrad Zuse");
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

При компиляции вижу ошибку C2664

> "std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>::basic_string(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,const
> _Alloc &)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char16_t [12]" в
> "std::initializer_list<_Elem>"    ConsoleApplication2 C:\Users\Александр\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.cpp 31

Объясните это поведение во всех подробностях, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте подумаем, а какой тип у u"Konrad Zuse" ? `char const[12]` - нет. Если бы он был такой, то тогда у строки std::string нашелся бы подходящий конструктор. Проверяем - удаляем просто буковку u и все компилируется (ожидаемо, потому что теперь тип действительно `char const[12]`).

У строки  u"Konrad Zuse" тип `wchar_t const[12]` (хотя некоторые компиляторы говорят `char16_t const[12]`, но это для них одно и тоже обычно) - массив широких символов. Поэтому, нужно исправить объявление на `std::u16string name;` (у типа `u16string` есть нужный конструктор) или делать преобразование типов.

То есть, код не компилируется, потому что компилятор не может найти подходящее разрешенное преобразование.